# Symfony 3.4 - No encoder has been configured for account

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, encryption, passwords

I'm trying to encrypt a password with Symfony 3.4

I followed the tutorial of the doc: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/registration_form.html

I first realized this tutorial on a blank project. It functioned. Then I tried to redo it on my main project, but with a small modification. The user does not enter a password when he registers. The generation of the password takes place later, in a function, when the admin activates the user.

Unfortunately, that does not seem to work, and I do not understand what configuration did I do wrong.

I've this error when i would like enable an user :

> No encoder has been configured for account
>   "Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User".

This is my code :

**Security.yml :**

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        PagesBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory: {memory: ~}
        in_database:
            entity:
                class: Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User
                property: username

        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User
                property: username
                # if you're using multiple entity managers
                # manager_name: customer

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: true

            provider: in_database

            form_login:
                login_path: security_login
                check_path: security_login

            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: informations

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~
```

**config.yml:**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']


# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

sensio_framework_extra:
   router:
        annotations: false

assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:    [ ]
   #java: /usr/bin/java
    java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        cssembed:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed.jar"        
            yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
        lessphp:
            file: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php"   
            apply_to: ".less$"
    assets:
        jquery_js:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"            
            filters: [?yui_js]
            output: js/jquery.min.js

        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
            filters:
                - lessphp
                - cssrewrite
            output: css/bootstrap.css            

        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/affix.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/alert.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/button.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/carousel.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/collapse.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/modal.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/popover.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/tab.js"
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/transition.js"
            filters: [?yui_js]
            output: js/bootstrap.js             
        fonts_glyphicons_eot:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"
        fonts_glyphicons_svg:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"
        fonts_glyphicons_ttf:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"
        fonts_glyphicons_woff:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"

            output: "fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"

stof_doctrine_extensions: 
    orm: 
        default: 
            sluggable: true

vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    twig: true
    storage: file_system

    mappings:
        paquet:
            uri_prefix: fichiers/packages
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/fichiers/packages/' 

            inject_on_load: true
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true

        notice:
            uri_prefix: fichiers/notices
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/fichiers/notices/' 

            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true

fos_ck_editor:
    configs:
        my_config:
            toolbar: [ ["Source", "-", "Save"], "/", ["Anchor"], "/", ["Maximize"] ]
            uiColor:                "#000000"
```

**User.php :**

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

       /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;



    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=254, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

     /**
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nbTelechargementsAuto", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $nbTelechargementsAuto;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActif", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActif=0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var \DateTime
    */
    private $createdAt;


    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isCreated", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isCreated=0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCreatedAt()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

        /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set prenom
     *
     * @param string $prenom
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPrenom($prenom)
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prenom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrenom()
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set nbTelechargementsAuto
     *
     * @param integer $nbTelechargementsAuto
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setNbTelechargementsAuto($nbTelechargementsAuto)
    {
        $this->nbTelechargementsAuto = $nbTelechargementsAuto;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nbTelechargementsAuto
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getNbTelechargementsAuto()
    {
        return $this->nbTelechargementsAuto;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActif
     *
     * @param boolean $isActif
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActif($isActif)
    {
        $this->isActif = $isActif;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActif
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsActif()
    {
        return $this->isActif;
    }


        /**
     * Set isCreated
     *
     * @param boolean $isCreated
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsCreated($isCreated)
    {
        $this->isCreated = $isCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isCreated
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsCreated()
    {
        return $this->isCreated;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ]);
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }


    /**
     * Activation du compte
     */
    public function activerCompte($nbPackages, $nbHomonymes)
    {

        if($this->getIsCreated() == 0)
        {
            $unUsername = $this->getNom();
            $unUsername .= ".";
            $unUsername .= $this->getPrenom();
            $unUsername = strtolower($unUsername);

            if($nbHomonymes > 0)
            {
                $nbHomonymes++;
                $unUsername .= $nbHomonymes;
            }


            $this->setUsername(strtolower($unUsername));
            $this->setNbTelechargementsAuto($nbPackages);
            $this->setCreatedAt();
            $this->setIsCreated(true);

        }

        $password = $this->generatePassword();

        $this->setPlainPassword($password);
        $this->setIsActif(true);

        return $this;
    }

    public function constructionUsername()
    {
        $unUsername = $this->getNom();
        $unUsername .= ".";
        $unUsername .=$this->getPrenom();

        return $unUsername;
    }

    /**
     * Désactivation du compte
     */
    public function desactiverCompte()
    {
        $this->setIsActif(false);
        $this->setCreatedAt();

        return $this;
    }

    public function registration()
    {
        // Passage Nom 1ère lettre Majuscule le reste minuscule
        $leNom = $this->getNom();
        $leNom = strtolower($leNom);
        $leNom = ucfirst($leNom);

        // Passage Nom 1ère lettre Majuscule le reste minuscule
        $lePrenom = $this->getPrenom();
        $lePrenom = strtolower($lePrenom);
        $lePrenom = ucfirst($lePrenom);

        $this->setNom($leNom);
        $this->setPrenom($lePrenom);
        $this->setCreatedAt();
    }

    /**
     * Génération d'un mot de passe
     * $nb_caractere = nombre de caractère du mdp
     * Pas de caractère qui se ressemble (L minuscule, 1 et i majuscule, Zéro et la lettre o.)
     * Sécurité supplémentaire avec : caractères speciaux: - + = $ % ! @ #
     * Pas d'espace pour éviter les erreurs
     */
    function generatePassword($nb_caractere = 7)
{
        $mot_de_passe = "";

        $chaine = "abcdefghjkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ023456789@!$?&";
        $longeur_chaine = strlen($chaine);

        for($i = 1; $i <= $nb_caractere; $i++)
        {
            $place_aleatoire = mt_rand(0,($longeur_chaine-1));
            $mot_de_passe .= $chaine[$place_aleatoire];
        }

        return $mot_de_passe;   
}


}
```

**Controller.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Controller;

use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Site\PagesBundle\Utils\Functions as mesFonctions;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

/**
 * User controller.
 *
 * @Route("utilisateurs")
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Liste des Utilisateurs
     *
     * @Route("/", name="utilisateurs_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager


        // Récupération des différents statuts d'utilisateurs

        $userActif = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->getUsersActifs(); //Utilisateurs actifs
        $userEnAttente = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->getUserEnAttente(); //Utilisateurs en attente de validation de compte
        $userDesactive = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->getUsersDesactives(); //Utilisateurs désactivés

        $statutUser = array("Utilisateurs actifs", "Utilisateurs en attente de validation", "Utilisateurs désactivés"); //Liste des différents statuts d'utilisateurs

        // On les regroupe dans un tableau pour faciliter le traitement
        $lesUtilisateurs = array();
        array_push($lesUtilisateurs,$userActif);
        array_push($lesUtilisateurs,$userEnAttente);
        array_push($lesUtilisateurs,$userDesactive);

        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', array(
            'statutUser' => $statutUser, //Liste des différents statuts d'utilisateur
            'lesUtilisateurs' => $lesUtilisateurs, //Tableau contenant les listes d'utilisateurs en fonction de leur statut
        ));
    }


// some functions

/**
     * Demande d'inscription
     *
     * @Route("/registration", name="utilisateurs_registration")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function demandeRegistration(Request $request)
    {

        $user = new User(); //Initialisation objet User (Utilisateur)
        $form = $this->createForm('Site\PagesBundle\Form\RegistrationType', $user); //Création formulaire de demande d'inscription
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        //Si le formulaire est saisi, on procède au traitement
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user); //On enregistre les premières informations de l'utilisateur, temporairement ( Nom, prenom, email)

            $lesUtilisateurs = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->findAll(); //Récupération de tous les utilisateurs pour vérification d'information

            $valide = true; //Initialisation du boolean pour signifier si l'inscription est valide

            foreach($lesUtilisateurs as $key=>$value ) //On vérifie pour chaque utilisateur si son email est la même que celle entrée par l'utilisateur désirant s'enregistrer
            {
                if( ($value->getEmail()) == ($user->getEmail()) ) // Si c'est le cas =>
                {
                    $valide = false; // La variable valide passe à false. La demande d'inscription ne sera pas validée
                }
            }

            if($valide == true) // Si l'email n'a pas déjà été utilisé
            {
                $user->registration(); // On passe au traitement d'enregistrement de la demande d'inscription
                $em->flush(); //On valide dans la BDD
                mesFonctions::sendMail($user->getEmail(),"demande",$user->getUsername()); //On envoi un mail pour informer l'utilisateur (sur l'email qu'il a renseigné)
                return $this->redirectToRoute('utilisateurs_registration', array('id' => $user->getId())); //redirection
            }

            else
            {
                $this->addFlash( //Si l'utilisateur a entré une adresse mail déjà utilisée, on l'en informe et on l'empêche de poursuivre
                    'info_edit',
                    'Email déjà utilisé.'
                );

                return $this->redirectToRoute('utilisateurs_registration', array('id' => $user->getId())); //Actualisation de la page de demande de création de compte
            }

        }

        //Si le formulaire n'est pas encore saisi, on affiche les informations liées au formulaire
        return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }


// My function which must encode the password :

/**
     * Activer le compte d'un utilisateur
     *
     * @Route("/activer/{id}", name="utilisateur_activation")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function activerUtilisateur(Request $request, $id, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager
        $nbPackages = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Paquet')->getNombrePackages(); //Récupération du nombre de packages (pour initialiser le nombre de téléchargements offert à l'utilisateur)

        $user = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->findOneById($id); // Récupération de l'objet User en fonction de l'ID fourni en paramètre

       // $lesUtilisateurs = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->findAll();

        $nbHomonymes = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->getHomonymes($user->getNom(),$user->getPrenom()); //Vérification des homonymes pour attribuer un bon identifiant pour l'utilisateur activé

        $user->activerCompte($nbPackages,$nbHomonymes); //Procédure d'activation du compte
        $em->persist($user); //Enregistrement des informations du compte
        $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);

      //  $user->setPassword($encoded);

        $em->flush(); //Validation dans la bDD

        mesFonctions::sendMail($user->getEmail(),"confirmation",$user->getUsername()); //Envoi d'un mail à l'utilisateur sur l'adresse mail qu'il a renseigné lors de sa demande d'inscription



        return $this->redirectToRoute('utilisateurs_index'); //Redirection à la liste des différents utilisateurs


    }
```

**I give precisely the function that poses a problem:**

```
/**
     * Activer le compte d'un utilisateur
     *
     * @Route("/activer/{id}", name="utilisateur_activation")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function activerUtilisateur(Request $request, $id, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager
        $nbPackages = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Paquet')->getNombrePackages(); //Récupération du nombre de packages (pour initialiser le nombre de téléchargements offert à l'utilisateur)

        $user = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->findOneById($id); // Récupération de l'objet User en fonction de l'ID fourni en paramètre

       // $lesUtilisateurs = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->findAll();

        $nbHomonymes = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->getHomonymes($user->getNom(),$user->getPrenom()); //Vérification des homonymes pour attribuer un bon identifiant pour l'utilisateur activé

        $user->activerCompte($nbPackages,$nbHomonymes); //Procédure d'activation du compte
        $em->persist($user); //Enregistrement des informations du compte
        $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);

      //  $user->setPassword($encoded);

        $em->flush(); //Validation dans la bDD

        mesFonctions::sendMail($user->getEmail(),"confirmation",$user->getUsername()); //Envoi d'un mail à l'utilisateur sur l'adresse mail qu'il a renseigné lors de sa demande d'inscription



        return $this->redirectToRoute('utilisateurs_index'); //Redirection à la liste des différents utilisateurs


    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
```

Because your Entity has namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity and your encoder configured for PagesBundle\Entity\User

So Site\PagesBundle\Entity !== PagesBundle\Entity

Answer (score 0):

If the last solution doesn't work, you should write your security file on `app/config/security.yml` like that :

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

See the doc here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded